# Use logical operators on images

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I have an MVC application java that captures an image from file, saving it to an object of type BufferedImage. I would like to do the AND logical operation between two images but do not know how to do, I can not find the sample code, where can I find it? 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `AND`ing two images? Do you want to `AND` each individual pixel with its counterpart in the other image?

Comment: What would you like the output of `IMG1 AND IMG2` to produce?

Comment: Logical AND???! - If your image is a binary image that makes sense! Otherwise explain more about what you are going to do!

Comment: Well, I have to open two images, convert them to binary and do the logical and between the two to get a third image as a result. I do not know if it is now more clear.

Comment: could be a solution OpenCV? how can I use OpenCV? Thanks